# Open primefaces dialog on error in prerenderview event listener

Tags: jsf, dialog, primefaces, listener, modal-dialog

I have a problem with open and close a primefaces dialog on error in a prerenderview event listener. I use the event listener to load data from a third-party system, which under some circumstances needs special authentication.

So far when the special authentication is required i set a property on a request scoped bean and use the visible property of the dialog to decide if the dialog should be visible or not.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="#{name}" resizable="false" modal="true"
            closable="false" id="#{name}Dialog" width="375"
            useWindow="true" 
            visible="#{specialAuthenticationBean.authenticationRequired}">
```

Hint: #{name} is an include parameter.

Is this the recommended way to do it?

If yes how can i close the dialog when the cancel or ok button was clicked?

So far for the cancel button i tried this with the following code but without success.

```
<p:commandButton id="cancel" value="#{messages['cancel']}" onclick="#{name}.hide()" type="button" />
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I tried out different things and found the cause. The dialog did not close because there were three includes for the same dialog with different parameters, but the visible-condition was true for all three dialogs.

And now i ask myself if it is really necessary to have three instances of the same dialog, only because the login buttons execute different actions (bean methods). What i really want to do is after one bean method invocation leads to open the authentication dialog, execute the same bean method again after submit the correct authentication data in the authentication dialog.

Comment: I don't think you can use EL inside id attribute, why don't you use a fixed id?

Comment: @Damian: should work just fine if it's an include or a composite. Rene: what exactly is the problem? The statement "without success" doesn't give much detail as to the problem. Does the dialog never close? Or does it close, but it reappears? Does it give a JS error? Does it give a Java error?  Etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. For further informations see my update in the original post.